# Silverlight based charts and graphs in an asp.net 3.0 application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-3.0, reporting

I wanted to build visually stunning graphs and charts ( with some animation, drill-down and interactivity in it) in an existing asp.net application.
The application is build using vs 2008.

I have two questions...

1. Which version of Silverlight will be best suited for this (v3 or v4) ?
2. What is the best option to create Charts and Graphs and embed it within the existing asp.net application ?

Note: I wanted to use Silverlight based charts only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have started using [visifire](http://visifire.com). It offers really amazing charts and graphs and even we can even play with its code. It is also well supported by the visifire developer community.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a specification that says you must use silverlight? I would suggest using [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com/) its an amazingly awesome javascript based charting library.. Its really [easy to use](http://highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use) and has a [TON of charts](http://highcharts.com/demo/)!

Comment: Yes we wanted to move towards Silverlight based interactive and animated reports as well as screens. We have a push from the Management.

Comment: haha ok, sorry about that ;) I know nothing about Silverlight, hopefully someone does! Best of luck!